# Error: Unable to access jarfile when launching java jar from C#

Tags: java, c#, jar, process

I am trying to launch a java jar in my C# app, however when executing this code, I get error message from proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd() --> Error: Unable to access jarfile. This means that java starts at least, but fails on jar access somehow. This is my code:

```
                            Process proc = new Process();
                            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java.exe\"";
                            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar \"J:\\jars\\Test.jar\"";
                            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                            proc.Start();
                            proc.WaitForExit();
                            Debug.WriteLine("Captured stderr from java process:");
                            Debug.WriteLine(proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```

To be 100% sure I'm wrapping paths in quotes, still no success.

when I try the same paths in console I am getting a proper launch of jar:

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\java.exe" -jar "J:\\jars\\Test.jar"
```

I am running an app from Visual Studio, it is launched as administrator. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Please be careful not to  misuse tags. Most tags have descriptions that you can read by hovering over them, and the descriptions usually outline cases where you should or shouldn't use the tags. For example, the `[visual-studio]` question should only be used for questions about the Visual Studio application, as opposed to code authored within the VS environment. I've removed that tag for you.

Comment: Have you tried setting `proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` to `j:\jars` ?

Comment: @VictorWilson Yes, no luck.
However, it works when I moved JAR to my "\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\" location and set workingDirectory to "\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111\\bin\\"as well..  Guess setting the java app Filename with absolute path breaks it..

Comment: @Llama I put this tag because I thought it's possible that how VS launches this might be the issue. My apologies.

Comment: Even when run from Visual Studio, your application is a standalone executable. You don't have to worry about it being how VS launches it. :) All VS does is launch the executable and attach the debugger to it.